# How to get mail with Exchange in Java

Tags: java, spring, email, exchangewebservices

Our mail server doesn't support imap and pop3 protocols so I can access new emails only with Exchange. What is the best way to get messages with Exchange? Is there some way to connect with Spring 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsofts [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) 1.2 seams to be a way. It is released under ["Microsoft Public License"](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi/Project/License.aspx) (from some [article](http://www.aljoscha-rittner.de/blog/archive/2010/12/15/javadev-microsoft-exchange-api-fuer-java/) it seems that this license is incompatible to GPL but once can use it for commercial products anyway)

Comment: Thank you! It's seems that these two tools the same. :)